# HTML Compressor for asp.net

Tags: html, html-compression

Anyone knows a good way or tool to compress the HTML that is sent to the client?

I was thinking in compressing the HTML in the .aspx files in the production server only, so maybe a tool for doing this would be the right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to enable GZIP, you can enable this in IIS

[iis6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true) | [iis7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik just released a compression utility as part of their RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX suite. If you aren't a customer you can check it out using the free, non-time-bombed trial of their controls.

Check out [this post](http://blogs.telerik.com/VladimirEnchev/Posts/08-12-16/HTTP_Compression_for_your_ASP_NET_AJAX_applications.aspx) and [this post](http://blogs.telerik.com/ToddAnglin/Posts/09-01-28/Optimization_Tips_RadCompression_Module.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

An article here about [ASP.NET white space cleaning with no runtime cost](http://omari-o.blogspot.com/2009/09/aspnet-white-space-cleaning-with-no.html).

Cleaning out the unnecessary whitespace has the effect of compressing the data.